# Getting data from specific index based on values from another DF

Tags: r

I have a df called "game_scores" that looks like:

```
Team     possessions    game_num
Duke     65             1
UNC      70             2
```

And another Df called "tempo" that looks like

```
Team     g0_tempo     g1_tempo
Duke     60           63
UNC      64           65
```

What im trying to do in this example would be to look up "Duke" tempo for g0_tempo (their tempo before game 1)

So I am looking to do something like `tempo[where tempo$team = Duke, col# = game_scores$game_num]` or in this case `tempo[1,1]`

Thanks

```
game_score$tempo_adj -> (mean(
  tempo$tempo[(game_scores$off == tempo$team), game_scores$`off game #`]
))
```

Comment: Please show your expected output

Comment: looking for game_score$tempo_adj col to have mean of game_score$possessions and matching teams possessions # in tempo$g0_tempo, in this case it would be 62.5 @akrun

Comment: Try `library(data.table);setDT(game_scores)[tempo, tempo_adj :=  (possessions + g0_tempo)/2,on = .(Team)]`

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a tidyverse-based solution: create a long version of `tempo` using `tidyr::pivot_longer()`, then merge in values using `dplyr::left_join()`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

tempo_lookup <- tempo %>%
  pivot_longer(
    ends_with("_tempo"),
    names_to = "game_num",
    values_to = "tempo",
    names_transform = ~ as.numeric(str_extract(.x, "\\d+")) + 1
  )

game_scores %>%
  left_join(tempo_lookup)
```

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  Team  possessions game_num tempo
  <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 Duke           65        1    60
2 UNC            70        2    65
```